# How to connect the ESP 8266 to local area network?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, esp8266, wifi, digital-communications

[image]I am working on an ESP8266 ESP-12E WiFi Module to turn an LED on and off.

Yes, I was able to turn on/turn off the LED with the help of Wifiserver and NodeMCU.

The problem is I want to connect the NodeMCU with my local area network on the PC.  My PC does not connect with Wi-Fi, only an Ethernet connection is present.

How can I connect the NodeMCU with my local area network connection, not with the mobile hotspot?

This is my code:

```c
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

/*Put your SSID & Password*/
const char* ssid = "ssid";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "password";  //Enter Password here

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

uint8_t LEDpin = D2;
bool LEDstatus = LOW;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println("ssid");

  //connect to your local wi-fi network
  WiFi.begin( "ssid", "password");

  //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print (".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.on("/ledon", handle_ledon);
  server.on("/ledoff", handle_ledoff);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  if(LEDstatus)
  digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);
  else
  digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
}

void handle_OnConnect() {
  LEDstatus = LOW;
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(false)); 
}

void handle_ledon() {
  LEDstatus = HIGH;
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(true)); 
}

void handle_ledoff() {
  LEDstatus = LOW;
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(false)); 
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

String SendHTML(uint8_t led){
  String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
  ptr +="<html>\n";
  ptr +="<head>\n";
  ptr +="<title>LED Control</title>\n";
  ptr +="</head>\n";
  ptr +="<body>\n";
  ptr +="<h1>LED</h1>\n";
  ptr +="<p>Click to switch LED on and off.</p>\n";
  ptr +="<form method=\"get\">\n";
  if(led)
  ptr +="<input type=\"button\" value=\"LED OFF\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/ledoff'\">\n";
  else
  ptr +="<input type=\"button\" value=\"LED ON\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/ledon'\">\n";
  ptr +="</form>\n";
  ptr +="</body>\n";
  ptr +="</html>\n";
  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: You will need a WiFi network. For LAN, an Ethernet port is required, which the ESP8266 does not have.

Comment: sir please tell me how I can do ? can I use esp32 modular for this or any other

Comment: ESP32 has a built in Ethernet MAC.  When connected to an external Ethernet PHY, you can connect an ESP32 to a wired Ethenet connection.

Comment: what about node MCU 8266? I need to read these things , can you provide me any link for this?

Comment: Does the ESP have an Ethernet port on it?

Comment: ESP32 does have but ESP8266 doesn't have

Answer (score 4):

If you have a WiFi Access Point (aka WiFi router) on your local LAN then you can connect your ESP8266 to that WiFi network and then its reachable from your PC via a IP address.

The IP address is in most cases automatically configured.

There is also support for "Multicast DNS" and if you use that there is no need to remember IP addresses, just use the name that you put into your Code for your ESP8266.

Ref. Multicast DNS, https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap08%20-%20mDNS.html

Comment: Sir, I am new in this project .thanks for advising me.

Comment: There is a way to add a Ethernet port to a ESP8266 by adding a Ethernet module with SPI interface, https://esp8266hints.wordpress.com/2018/02/13/adding-an-ethernet-port-to-your-esp-revisited/ . I wouldn't recommend it since its more cumbersome and to get a WiFi AP should be more feasible.

Comment: sir, I need to explain to you one more time, what I am doing. simply I am controlling a led through node MCU via wifi server but my professor said to me that in our college personal computer we don't have wifi connection so, we can't control the led until if we are not connected with the same network.so we need to build a network or solution to connect the node MCU with computer pc's. sir, I am a learner, I just want a path or source where I can start my work.

Comment: sir, please help me. what you suggest to me I will follow the same steps.

Comment: Do the PC have internet? Can you setup a mobile WiFi AP that the NodeMCU can connect to? If yes, then it could be done via internet, but that's quite complex. If you can get your hands on a WiFi router with Ethernet and connect the college PC to that router and the NodeMCU to the same then you have a simple solution.

Comment: yes, I can connect the pc with the internet,. B the way I am using the same pc right now , where I will do the project.i have connected the node MCU with my mobile hotspot behaves as sta mode, and second I have done the access mode , node MCU acts as server.

Comment: "If you can get your hands on a WiFi router with Ethernet and connect the college PC to that router and the NodeMCU to the same then you have a simple solution" can you explain to me more .i am not able to get it.

Comment: If you connect your college PC to an WiFi router (they normally also have Ethernet) and the ESP8266, then they are on the same IP network and can reach each other.

Comment: @Mats Karlsson He needs to be aware that most large universities will have security on their networks that will stop him from connecting devices without a key and will prevent connecting devices like this.

Comment: @David That is an task that I assume that the Professor have informed "Arijeet Roy" about.

Comment: yes, you are right. the professor will allow me and will to the college for this task. can you tell me how I will do my task? please.somebody was telling me that you must read port forwarding. I need to edit a program or use networking.

Comment: @ArijeetRoy I can not give that detailed instructions, now you have got some leads and you need to study them.

Comment: yes you are right .but I am not finding any right leads, all of them confusing me. at least i need to know which path will be right.please help me

Comment: WiFi AP and mDNS.

Comment: @Mats Karlsson sir, I have read some network protocols , in which how to control the esp8266 from anywhere. exactly it's was not controlling the esp8266 , they are doing port forwarding to control the system from remote desktop locations. however, I need to follow the same process I guess.please tell me if I am doing the wrong approach.

Comment: If the PC and the ESP is on the same network, there is no need for port forwarding. Port forwarding is only needed to go through a Firewall from the outside to the inside.

Comment: HELLO , SIR SORRY I WAS BUSY IN THIS SAME WORK. I CAN'T SEE THE MESSAGE .RIGHT NOW I AM ABLE TO CHAT WITH YOU. PLEASE MESSAGE ME WHEN YOU ARE FREE